# Why echo $var is different

Tags: php

```
<?php
function f(& $var){$var = rand(); return $var;}
echo f($var ="a_").'<br/>'; /* outpu a random number */
echo $var.'<br/>'; /*but don't change global variables, it still is "1<br/>", no the same like up line */
echo f($var).'<br/>'; /* outpu a random number */
echo $var.'<br/>'; /* haved change, the same like up line */
?>
```

*run up code and output  text like under block*

> 28486
>   a_
>   25863
>   25863

Wwhy can't change the `$var` in the first call?

```
<?php
function f(& $var, & $isRefer){$var = rand(); global $gVar; var_dump(array('are they same?' => $isRefer === $gVar)); return $var;}
$gVar = 'global var';
echo f($var ="a_", $gVar = & $gVar).'<br/>'; /* outpu a random number */
echo $var.'<br/>'; /*but don't change global variables, it still is "1<br/>", no the same like up line */
echo f($var, $gVar).'<br/>'; /* outpu a random number */
echo $var.'<br/>'; /* haved change, the same like up line */
?>
```

-the code output like-

> array(1) {
>     ["are they same?"]=>
>     bool(true)
>   }
>   14802
>   a_
>   array(1) {
>     ["are they same?"]=>
>     bool(true)
>   }
>   19107
>   19107

**so i think it is pass value like `f($var = 'd')` by "refer"**

Comment: Say whaaaaaaaaat

Comment: You know, this might be interesting, and you might have a real issue there. But the presentation is not usable. You need to cut out one actual example, and showcase one variable output pair. Nobody can follow that as one big code and var_dump blob otherwise.

Comment: I'm stuck on a title, but after editing I'd say this question is alright for reopening.

Comment: f($var ="1<br/>"); is executing the assignment of $var ="1<br/>" but it isn't passing $var to the function, but the result of that assignment... so $var remains unchanged.

Comment: but `f($var='dd')` look like is pass value by "refer",under line is a test

Comment: Now I'm regretting reopening this question. How on _Earth_ is anyone supposed to read your copy-pasta comment?

Comment: i'm sorry.i'm come here first;the code i put it in the first comment.

Comment: @qidizi - You might __think__ that it should pass $var by reference, but you'd be wrong. Assignments such as $var="3<br />" have a result as well, and the result isn't $var... so $var doesn't get passed

Comment: Does your question have something to do with E=MC²??

Comment: `f($var ="a_", ($gVar = & $gVar))` is the same as `f($var ="a_", $gVar = & $gVar)`,is it like `$b = ($a = 1)`?but why `$isRefer === $gVar` return `TRUE`?

Comment: @qidizi `f($var = 'foo')` is not the same as `f($var)`.

Comment: if it pass a result(the mean it is copy the result)  to `function f(& $var)`,can i test if they "memory address " is the same with `$gVar` and the pass result?how can i to do?

Comment: PHP is not C, there is no "memory address" you can compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing variables by reference is a special case of function calling. Typically only the value of an *expression* is passed into the function as parameter.

```
f(3 * 4);
```

Here `3 * 4` is an expression that evaluates to `12`, so `12` is passed into the function. A function that expects *variables* to be passed by reference though is different, because it needs a variable:

```
function f(&$var) { ... }
```

The purpose of passing by reference is to be able to modify the passed *variable*, not just a value. As such, you need to actually pass it a *variable*, not just a value. Calling the function with something like `f(3 * 7)` doesn't make much sense in this case. Well, `f($var = 'foo')` is the same thing. `$var = 'foo'` is an *expression*, it's not simply a variable. Therefore only the result of the expression (the value) is passed, not any variable that happens to appear in the expression.

To illustrate that better, which variable should be passed when doing `f($foo + $bar)`? The answer is that it just doesn't work that way. To pass a variable by reference, you can only use a variable as the parameter, not an expression.

```
f($var);
```

Comment: ok,i know now,it is copy.`function f(& $var, & $isRefer){$var = rand(); $isRefer='kkkkk'; global $gVar;var_dump($gVar);...`;thanks all of every one!!

Comment: Just for the love of god, don't write code like this. Pointless pass-by-reference and `global` in the same function is too many sins at once. Pass-by-reference has its uses, but you *hardly* ever need it. It's mostly a performance tweak for things like `shuffle(&$array)`. Don't overuse it!

Comment: Nicely expressed deceze: you've managed to translate into English what I was struggling to say

Answer (score 1):

```
f($var ="a_");
```

does not pass $var as an argument to f(), but passes the result of that assignment to f()... This is an unassigned string value equal to the string that you have assigned tp $var (assuming that the assignment was successful), but isn't a reference to $var itself. That's why $var is assigned, but isn't changed by f()

Answer (score 0):

This question confuses me.

So this is your initial code:

```
<?php
function f(& $var){
    $var = rand();
    return $var;
}
echo f($var ="a_").'<br/>'; /* outpu a random number */
echo $var.'<br/>'; /*but don't change global variables, it still is "1<br/>", no the same like up line */
echo f($var).'<br/>'; /* outpu a random number */
echo $var.'<br/>'; /* haved change, the same like up line */
?>
```

In your function it doesn't matter what I pass to it, because the second line `$var = rand();` is ALWAYS going to overwrite whatever value you pass to the function.

So if I did `f("jordanmoore");` after the first line this would no longer be "jordanmoore," rather it would be a random value.

Next is this line: `echo f($var ="a_").'<br/>'; /* outpu a random number */`

I'm not sure why you are trying to set `$var` here. If you want to pass "a_" to the function then just call `f("a_");`. But I'm not sure why you're passing anything to the function when the value is always overwritten. If you want the format to be "a_somerandomnumber" then perhaps `echo "a_".f(null);` would be better to use?

I'm going to hesitate a guess here and rewrite your function to the following

```
<?php
function f(& $var=null){
    $var = rand();
    return $var;
}
?>
```

Then you may use it like so:

```
<?php
function f(& $var=null){
    $var = rand();
    return $var;
}

echo f(); //output a random number
echo "a_".f(); //out put a_ with a random number after the underscore
$myRandomVariable = f(); //put a random number in a variable
echo $myRandomVariable; //echo this variable
echo "a_".$myRandomVariable; //echo this variable after a_
echo "a_$myRandomVariable"; //same as above
?>
```

Hope this helps.

**edit**

You can also then do:

```
<?php
function f(& $var=null){
    $var = rand();
    return $var;
}
$myValue = 0;
f($myValue); //store a random number in "$myValue"
echo $myValue; //echo the random number
?>
```

Comment: i can write a economic code,but i don't understand how they do : `f($var = 'e')` and `function f(& $var)`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with `f($var = 'e')` because this is a statement. `$var = 'e'` will execute first and then your line of code turns in to `f(true);` because it completed successfully. In the other line `function f(& $var);` the ampersand character `&` is being used so that `$var` can be written to instead of just being read. The **edit** part of my answer demonstrates what the `&` part of `function f(& $var);` does.

Comment: FYI: `$var = 'e'` evaluates to `'e'`, not `true`.